# Prevent images to download on every scroll

Tags: swift, firebase, sdwebimage, firebase-storage

I am trying to prevent my `tableview` to load images from **Firebase** on every up and down scroll. How should I do that? I don't even understand why it is doing so since I am using the 3rd party library called **"MSWebImage"** which should `cache` them somewhere.

I also tried the 3rd party library called **"KingFisher"** which did the same thing.

**Edit:** I noticed that while scrolling up and down something is caching into memory on every scroll but the disk is zero

This is the code I use to get the images:

```
let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["Products"] as? String

FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(productImageref!).png").downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
            }else{
         cell.snusProductImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
    }
})
```

Comment: I have the same issue man. Even if i'm using Parse, I have a collection view and i bring some images... Then i'm caching them with `Kingfisher` but when i'm on the cell 30 and i want to go back to the 1st cell it will load it again (shows the indicator etc.) and i'm looking for a way not to load it again but to show it at once.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios If you find anything please let me know. I tried manyally caching but I think it is not good since the library should do it.

Comment: I found out a solution that worked perfect for me without any library. follow this guide here 

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-part-5-async-image-loading-and-caching/

Comment: But i dont know if with firebase you can get the actual URL Link. Because with parse you can.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the touches methods like touchesBegan or touchesMoved and then call self tableView.reloadData() every time the touchesMoved Method is called.

Comment: I think you didn't read the question? :) Your suggestion would load every picture again but I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should download the data in the viewDidLoad so that only unloaded once.

stored in a dictionary https addresses.

```
func convertGsToHttps (keySection: String, pathGsToConvert: String) {

    FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(pathGsToConvert).downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }else{
            self.urlHttpsSection.updateValue(url! , forKey: keySection)

        }
    })
}
```

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
let setImage = section.value as! String //Getting the key to my dictionary
    //loadData()




    for clave in urlGsSecciones.keys where clave == setImage
    {
        if setImage == clave
        {
            cell.imageCellBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.imageCellBackground.clipsToBounds = true
            let urlHttps = urlHttpsSection[setImage]
            print("urlHttps", urlHttps)
            cell.imageCellBackground.sd_setImageWithURL(urlHttps)
        }
    }
```

**